# How to change a tension symbol from an arrow to a pair of plus and minus signs?

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pnodes
    (0,2){A}
    (4,2){B}
    \resistor
    [
        intensitylabel=$i_1$,
        intensitylabeloffset=.3,
        tensionlabel=$v_1$,
        tensionoffset=-.5,
        tensionlabeloffset=-.8,
    ](A)(B){$R$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to change the above diagram to the following.

[image]

How to change the tension symbol from an arrow to a pair of plus and minus signs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the `pst-circ.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-circ/ or the latest TeXLive update from today knows `tensionstyle=pm` (the default is `tensionstyle=line`). Should work  for all elements.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pnodes(0,2){A}(4,2){B}
\resistor[
        intensitylabel=$i_1$,
        intensitylabeloffset=.3,
        tensionlabel=$v_1$,
        tensionoffset=-.5,
        tensionlabeloffset=-.8,
        tensionstyle=pm         ](A)(B){$R$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...hot off the press I guess.

Comment: I think `arrow` is more semantic and clearer than `line`.

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE provides a starred version of `\resistor` which sets a `+`/`-` instead of an arrow:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ
\makeatletter
\let\@oldresistor\resistor
\def\resistor{\@ifstar\@newresistor\@oldresistor}
\def\@newresistor{\@ifnextchar[\@newresistor@i{\@newresistor@i[]}}
\def\@newresistor@i[#1](#2)(#3)#4{{%
  \def\pst@tension##1##2{%
    \psset{linestyle=none}% Remove lines
    \ifPst@tension
      \pcline[arrows=-,fillstyle=none,%linestyle=none,
        offset=\psk@tension@offset](##1)(dipole@1)
      \ncput[npos=.9]{\pnode{tension@1}}
      \pcline[arrows=-,fillstyle=none,%linestyle=none,
        offset=-\psk@tension@offset](##2)(dipole@2)
      \ncput[npos=.9]{\pnode{tension@2}}
      \ifPst@directconvention
        \ifPst@Dconvention
          \rput{0}(tension@1){$\scriptstyle-$}\rput{0}(tension@2){$\scriptstyle+$}
        \else
          \rput{0}(tension@1){$\scriptstyle+$}\rput{0}(tension@2){$\scriptstyle-$}
        \fi
      \else
        \ifPst@Dconvention
          \rput{0}(tension@1){$\scriptstyle+$}\rput{0}(tension@2){$\scriptstyle-$}
        \else
          \rput{0}(tension@1){$\scriptstyle-$}\rput{0}(tension@2){$\scriptstyle+$}
        \fi
      \fi
      \pcline[arrows=-,linestyle=none,fillstyle=none,%
        offset=\psk@tension@label@offset](dipole@1)(dipole@2)
      \ncput[nrot=\psk@label@angle]{%
    \csname\psk@tension@labelcolor\endcsname\psk@tension@label}
    \fi
  }
  \@oldresistor[#1](#2)(#3){#4}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
\pnodes
    (0,2){A}
    (4,2){B}
    \resistor*
    [
        intensitylabel=$i_1$,
        intensitylabeloffset=.3,
        tensionlabel=$v_1$,
        tensionoffset=-.5,
        tensionlabeloffset=-.8,
    ](A)(B){$R$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The macro `\pst@tension` is responsible for drawing the arrow and label below the `\resistor`. It has been changed to move the location of the endpoints of the lines (formerly midway between `A`/`B` and the edge of the resistor using a `npos=.5` placement) using an `npos=.9` placement. Also, instead of drawing the line with an arrow, it now `\rput`s a `+`/`-` at the respective "tension" ends. The entire definition of `\pst@tension` is otherwise kept the same, so it should work with other options/definitions (including a change in direction).

Comment: This should be added to the `pst-circ` package to facilitate users to use it.